# Xcode find in document stuck in case-sensitive

Tags: xcode, find

When in Xcode editing code for my objective C files, I often press Command-F to bring up the little Find-In-Document banner across the top. Sometimes this gets stuck in case-sensitive search, and when it does that it also won't loop through the entire document and sometimes won't even display the selected found string.

I can't find any options to turn off the case sensitivity, and I never intentionally turned it on. I've restarted xcode several times hoping that would be it but it's changed nothing.

Slightly off-topic, but this was the best place I could think of to ask this question. Thanks for any response!

EDIT: I've also tried restarting the computer. Still no dice. Also this happens on any project I open in xcode and is not specific to one project.

Comment: Not sure, but you might want to ask on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Thanks good idea. I've opened a question there too, but this seems to be on the fence between the two sites and there are probably more people using Xcode here, so I figured I'd start here.

Comment: When you press Cmd-F, clicking on the little magnifying glass next to the search input doesn't bring up a menu where you can check/uncheck Ignore Case?

Comment: AHH how did I miss that! Somehow ignore-case and wrap around got unchecked from in there. Either way I've changed it in there and it's working like regular now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Anna's comment is the correct answer: When you press Cmd-F, clicking on the little magnifying glass next to the search input brings up a menu where you can check/uncheck Ignore Case.

Comment: too damn obvious, to ignorant to notice. Seems that most common things are hardest to notice. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can set parameters for search by **clicking on magnifier** placed in left-side of search-bar.
There is provision to select/de-select **"Match Case"** i.e. case-sensitive search on pop-up shown.
Below is screenshot for the same.

[image: Screenshot depicting search options available]